# multiple submit buttons in from table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, flask

Needing a bit of help and advice. I have have a form wrapped inside a table and on every row there is a form input and a submit button on that row, what I am trying to do is capture the user input from that row and submit button that was pressed. One thing that is stumping me is usually to capture the form input value we would pass whatever the `name` value is in the input tag and pass that to the backend in my case its flask so i would do something like `comment = request.form.get('comment_1')`. Can someone help me figure out how to know what button and input name value tag were clicked so from that rows input I can retrieve that input value?

Also I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/ot2vmzfp/11/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form metohd="POST">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text"placeholder="Comment" name="comment_1" id="comment_1"></td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="button-1" value="button-1" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
         <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text"placeholder="Comment" name="comment_2" id="comment_2"></td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="button-2" value="button-2" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
         <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Comment" name="comment_3" id="comment_3"></td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="button-3" value="button-3" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.activeElement`

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()   
  let el_TR = document.activeElement.closest('tr')
    
  if (el_TR)
    {
    let inEl = el_TR.querySelector('input')
    console.clear()
    console.log('input _name:', inEl.name, ', _value:', inEl.value )
    }
  }
```

```html
-<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
<form metohd="POST" name="my-form">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text"placeholder="Comment" name="comment_1" ></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text"placeholder="Comment" name="comment_2" ></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Comment" name="comment_3" ></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```